# Trying to implement javascript popup

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a javascript popup on my webpage and it's not working. I've written it all out in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/68vGZ/

and the code is here:

```
HTML
<div id="header-links">
    <button id="aboutinfo">About</button>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="popup">
        <p>About Info Here</p>
        <button id="closeaboutinfo">Close</button>
    </div>
    <button id="contactinfo">Contact</button>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="popup">
        <p>Contact with this email address</p>
        <button id="closecontactinfo">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>


CSS
#overlay {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:99999;
}
#popup {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    margin-top:-75px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border:2px solid #000;
    z-index:100000;
}


JavaScript
window.onload - function () {
    document.getElementById("aboutinfo").onclick = function () {
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        popup.style.display = "block";
    };

    document.getElementById("closeaboutinfo").onclick = function () {
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        popup.style.display = "none";
    };

    document.getElementById("contactinfo").onclick = function () {
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        popup.style.display = "block";
    };

    document.getElementById("closecontactinfo").onclick = function () {
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        popup.style.display = "none";
    };
}
```

The buttons show and the text is hidden, but i just can't work out why they won't trigger... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you aware you have elements with the same id?

Comment: The error is quite trivial. It should be `window.onload = function () ...`, not with the minus sign.

Comment: Only the overlay and popup though as far as i can see. I want these to stay the same and the content in them will change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three problems:

Firstly, this isn't valid:

```
window.onload - function () {
              ^
```

Your `-` symbol needs to be changed to a `=`:

```
window.onload = function () {
```

Secondly you have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute - this is invalid HTML and your JavaScript will only detect the first matched element. You should change these to `class` attributes and use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`.

Thirdly, you need to tell JSFiddle to place your JavaScript in the document `body`.

[**Fixed JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/68vGZ/2/).

Comment: Thanks for your help but i'm really confused now. I just put this into Brackets and it won't work... The text isn't hidden by default, it's all inline. I linked a separate .js file in the <head> using <script src="js/info.js"></script> and it won't work...

Comment: What do you mean? I've put the CSS into the main (and only) CSS file for the website, and have since saved it. Still no luck...?

Comment: @user3910071 if you've updated your `id` attributes to `class` attributes you'll need to use the `.` class selector rather than the `#` id selector.

Comment: Yeah i've done that. Am i right in thinking i should update id to class on "overlay" and "popup"? As they were sharing?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't respond, I had to leave to go to a house viewing. Glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using Bootstrap.  They make it easy for you to create nice looking popups with rich functionality right out of the box.  Here is a link where you can get bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com

They have much more to offer besides nice popups (modals).  Definitely worth checking out even if this answer doesn't help you out.